# Error while destroy admob view on canvas

Tags: android, admob, android-windowmanager

I use this code for rendering AdMob view on canvas.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
windowParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
windowParams.x = 0;
windowParams.y = 0;
windowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
windowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
windowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
windowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
windowParams.windowAnimations = 0;

WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();

adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, YOU_ADMOB_SITE_ID);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
wm.addView(adView, windowParams);
```

///////////

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
if (adView != null) {
  adView.destroy();
}
super.onDestroy();
}
```

I always get an error at this line wm.addView(adView, windowParams);

Error: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity has leaked window com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView that was originally added here

Please help!

Comment: Try to remove the admob from the Window Manager and then call `adview.destroy()`.